# How to save training data set [pixel values] from earth engine during classification?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-fusion-tables

Link to Earth Engine code:https://code.earthengine.google.com/4da2d54d1ece4229b76c52a9d921ca70
**Below I have pasted my code:**

```js
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');
  var cloudBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(10).int();
  var cirrusBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(11).int();
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0).and(
             qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

// Map the function over one year of data and take the median.
var composite = s2.filterDate('2018-03-01', '2018-03-31')
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
                  .filterBounds(ft)
                  .map(maskS2clouds)
                  .median();

// Display the results.

Map.setCenter(87.32,22.40, 6);
//Map.addLayer(composite, {bands: ['B6', 'B4', 'B3'], min: 0, max: 0.3},'fcc');


var landcover_roi = composite.clip(ft);

Map.addLayer(landcover_roi, {bands: ['B6', 'B4', 'B3'], min: 0, max: 0.3},'clip');
Map.addLayer(ft, {}, 'From Fusion Table');

// Make a palette: a list of hex strings.
//var newfc = waterbody.merge(river).merge(fallow).merge(builtup).merge(forest).merge(agriland);
var newfc=waterbody.merge(agriland).merge(built_up);
//print(newfc);
//create training data
var bands = ['B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7','B8', 'B8A'];
var training = landcover_roi.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection: newfc, 
  properties: ['class'], 
  scale: 30
});
print(training);
//Train the classifier
var classifier = ee.Classifier.cart().train({
  features: training, 
  classProperty: 'class', 
  inputProperties: bands
});
var classified = landcover_roi.select(bands).classify(classifier);
//Display classification
Map.centerObject(newfc, 8);
var trainAccuracy = classifier.confusionMatrix();
print('Resubstitution error matrix: ', trainAccuracy);
print('Training overall accuracy: ', trainAccuracy.accuracy());

//Map.addLayer(sentinel, {bands: ['B6', 'B4', 'B3'], max: 0.3}, 'sentinel image');
Map.addLayer(classified, {min: 1, max: 3, palette: ['#0f1cbf', '#3df6ff', '#dfc723','#d87cf0','#335124','#81ff41']}, 'classification');
//Map.addLayer(newfc);
//Export the image to drive Storage.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: classified ,
  description: 'classifiedRGB',
  scale: 20,
  maxPixels:350000000,
  region:ft
});
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: newfc,
  description:'vectorsToDriveExample',
  fileFormat: 'KML'
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `geometries` to **true**, then export to a table asset.  Snippet:

```
var training = landcover_roi.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection: newfc, 
  properties: ['class'], 
  scale: 30,
  geometries: true
});

Export.table.toAsset({
  collection: training, 
  description: 'foo', 
  assetId: 'foo'
});
```